# Delete Duplicates MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, realm, mongoose-schema

When web-scraping my code is sometimes fetching duplicate entries to MongoDB Realm. How can I make my MongoDB database contain only unique entries and remove duplicates?

Below is the code from MongoDB Realm:

```
exports = async function(payload, response) {
 const {jobsPerPage = 100, page = 0} = payload.query;

  let query = {};
  if (payload.query.jobPosition) {
    query = { $text: { $search: payload.query.jobPosition } }
  }
    
  const collection = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("sample_jobs").collection("glassdoordbs");
  let jobsList = await collection.find(query).sort({featured: -1}).skip(page*jobsPerPage).limit(jobsPerPage).toArray()
  let allResults = await collection.count(query).then(num => num.toString())
  
  jobsList.forEach(job => {
    job._id = job._id.toString();
  });

  const responseData = {
    jobs: jobsList,
    page: page.toString(),
    filters: {},
    entries_per_page: jobsPerPage.toString(),
    total_results: await collection.count(query).then(num => num.toString()),
    totalPages: await Math.ceil(allResults / jobsPerPage).toString()
  };
  
  return responseData;
};
```

An example of duplicate entries I get:

[image]

Comment: Can share some data showing what kind of duplicate entries you are getting and what you are expecting?

Comment: Just added the screenshot with an example to the question. The website I'm scraping sometimes shows multiple of the same jobs on the same page, hence, the scraper sometimes fetches data of the same job multiple times. I would like this to be saved only once in the MongoDB Realm.

Comment: Those "duplicates" have different URLs.  What should be compared to determine they are duplicate?

Comment: @Joe If ```jobPosition``` and ```jobDescription``` are the same in another object, I'd determine this as a duplicate for my use case

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of when you are *web-scraping*. check to see if the newly read entry already exists in your database and if so, ignore it? Seems pretty straight forward. no?